# How to enable framework localization in macOS command line tool?

Tags: macos, localization

In a normal macOS .app package, I can get localized text from various frameworks, like `AVCaptureDevice.localisedName` or `NSError`'s `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey`, as long as I have added the system's current language as a localization in Xcode. This amounts to an .lproj directory being added inside the app package's Contents/Resources directory.

But command line tools don't have any such directory.

So how can I get the same behaviour from those frameworks in a command line tool?